# How do I resolve a PDO exception (SQLIte) error while deploying on Azure?

Tags: 7, database

I'm deploying a Drupal site to an Azure App (do not have any choice in the matter, so no point suggesting other environments) and do not have access to it directly (no SSH) as it is a infra-structure as service sort of thing. Long story short is that I deploy it via github. I'm using Sqlite and all works fine on my local environment. However when I do push it to Azure via Github, I get the following error: `PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of D:\home\site\wwwroot\includes\lock.inc).`

I have changed all files and folder permissions (for test purposes I even set all to 0777) and it did not work.

Any ideas on how to get this setup working?

Comment: It's 99.99% definitely a permissions issue, but with the database not the files. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-manage-logins/

Comment: It's 0.01% definitely bad path on settings.php. Be sure the path is absolute and correct. For exemple, not sites/default/files/.ht.sq.lite must be /home/user/blabla/sites/default/files/.ht.sq.lite